# Excel 2013 VBA Import unique data from .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import, duplicates

I'm trying to make an Excel macro which enables me to import a .csv file and check for duplicates in the active worksheet at the same time. The .csv file is constantly updating, at fixed times I will import the file. The first items therefore already exist in the worksheet and should not be imported again. This can be checked by comparing the 2nd value with column B in the worksheet.

Can this be done at once, or should I import the data to a separate worksheet first and then compare and copy?

Comment: "2nd value with column B" not sure what this means exactly.  Could you perhaps post some sample data with the columns labeled.

Comment: I mean the 2nd value in the .CSV file is copied to column B of the worksheet (the 1ste value to A, the 3th to C, etc. The second CSV value (of each row) should be compared to the values in column B. If it already exist is shouldn't be imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do the comparison at the import stage. Depending on how much data you have it could actually take longer than importing it all then filtering out the duplicates.

Rather I would append the new csv data to the end then use the built in function to remove duplicates. This method works well if you prefer to keep the already in place duplicate and only delete the 2nd onward.

You would use something like the following where rngRange is all the data to be checked for duplicates:

`rngRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes`

Comment: Thanks, I will continue with this way. It just felt a little as an "extra step" which I was not sure if it could be done easier.

Comment: I've been surprised sometimes how something that feels like an extra step can actually be faster. You can certainly do the compare at the import stage, just that you've got to have a loop check each import row, try and match it against your existing data, then copy if no match is found. It's actually a lot of code compared to copy all and remove duplicates :-)